# In Python: check if file modification time is older than a specific datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote this code in c# to check if a file is out of date:

```
 DateTime? lastTimeModified = file.getLastTimeModified();
        if (!lastTimeModified.HasValue)
        {
            //File does not exist, so it is out of date
            return true;
        }
        if (lastTimeModified.Value < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-synchIntervall))
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
           return false;
        }
```

How do I write this in python?

I tried this in python.

```
statbuf = os.stat(filename)
if(statbuf.st_mtime < datetime.datetime.now() - self.synchIntervall):
    return True
 else:
    return False
```

I got the following exception

```
message str: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Comment: what have you done so far? try to be more specific about what you don't know. Don't expect someone else to write all the code for you.

Comment: I edited my answer to conlcude what i have tried.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to use the [`os.path.getmtime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) function (in combination with the [`time.time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) one). This should give you an idea:

```
>>> import os.path as path
>>> path.getmtime('next_commit.txt')
1318340964.0525577
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1322143114.693798
```

Comment: what exactly does this strange number describe? And How do I compare it with a date?

Comment: @Luke - They are timestamps in [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), whose unit of measurement is seconds. You use them as regular real numbers: by adding and subtracting them. So if `time_a` - `time_b` gives you `3600` it means an hour has passed between the two...

Comment: Little adjustment to @mac answer to make it full: `import os.path as path
import time
def is_file_older_than_x_days(file, days=1):
 file_time = path.getmtime(file)
 # Check against 24 hours
 if (time.time() - file_time) / 3600 > 24*days:
  print('older than %s days' % days)
 else:
  print('not older than %s days' % days)`

Answer (score 13):

@E235's comment in the accepted answer worked really well for me.

Here it is formatted;

```
import os.path as path
import time

def is_file_older_than_x_days(file, days=1): 
    file_time = path.getmtime(file) 
    # Check against 24 hours 
    return ((time.time() - file_time) / 3600 > 24*days)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a generic solution using timedelta, that works for *seconds*, *days*, *months* and even *years*...

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_file_older_than (file, delta): 
    cutoff = datetime.utcnow() - delta
    mtime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file))
    if mtime < cutoff:
        return True
    return False
```

This can be used as follows.

To detect a file older than 10 seconds:

```
from datetime import timedelta

is_file_older_than(filename, timedelta(seconds=10))
```

To detect a file older than 10 days:

```
from datetime import timedelta

is_file_older_than(filename, timedelta(days=10))
```

If you are ok installing external dependencies, you can also do months and years:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta # pip install python-dateutil

is_file_older_than(filename, relativedelta(months=10))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that your synchIntervall is not a datetime object so Python can't decrease it. You need to use another datetime object.
like:

```
synchIntervall = datetime.day(2)
```

or

```
synchIntervall = datetime.hour(10)
```

or a more complete one:

```
synchIntervall = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

the first three are required.
This way you determinate the variable in a value which can be  calculated with the datetime.datetime.now() value.