# How to get the list of files in a repository that have not been updated/changed in the last 6 months

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab, filesystems

I want to create a report which will contain the name & location of files that have not been updated/changed in the last 6 months. I am thinking of writing a script to achieve the report that shall run as scheduled pipeline in gitlab ci.

```
    - git fetch origin master
    - git checkout -b master
    - find python -type f -mtime -2 | tee python.txt
```

I used the above snippet in the Gitlab CI runner, it returned the files that were not even edited in the last 2 days.

Comment: Check out: [In Python: check if file modification time is older than a specific datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258145/in-python-check-if-file-modification-time-is-older-than-a-specific-datetime)

Comment: _this doesn't do my job_ is not a description of your problem. What does it do that you did not expect or what does it miss that you expected? If it reports also directories, simply add `-type f`to limit the search to real files. If what you are interested in is not file modification dates on your filesystem but on the git repository then do not use `find`, use `git`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet How do I print the console output of this command in  a txt file or any file which can be used as a report?

Comment: Simply redirect its output to a file: `find directory -type f -mtime +180 > report.log`. But please, edit your question and explain precisely what your problem is. Not in comment, directly in the body of your question.

Comment: I suspect that you mix up between modifications on your filesystem and modifications on your remote git repository. If there is a file on the `master` branch of your git repository that has not been updated since 6 months but that you do not have yet on your local copy, when fetching and checking out it will be created and its local modification time will be just now. Same if this file exists in two different version in two different branches. Evey time you switch from one branch to the other its local modification time will become just now.

Comment: So the question is: are you interested in the modification times of your local copy or in the modification times on your remote git repository? For the former `find` is the right tool. For the latter use `git` to get the date/time of the last commit that updated each file.

Comment: Did some research, found the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
create-depreciated-report:
  script:
    - git fetch --unshallow
    - yum -y install git-tools
    - git restore-mtime
    - find . -type f -mtime +180 | tee report.txt
  artifacts:
    name: Deprecated files
    paths:
      - 'report.txt'
```